# What is that term to describe the wing motion range?

Tags: wing, terminology

What is that term naming the range of motion of the wings when on the ground (hanging/drooping) then bends upwards during flight?

Comment: [Wing flex](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14719/is-wing-flex-good) is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The term that you are looking for is [**Wing Flex**](https://aviationpro25blog.wordpress.com/2016/07/30/first-blog-post/). The extent of flex is a product of the material.The wing needs a stated definitive strength. With metal, that transforms into a given amount of flex. IOW, the flex, is basically just a by-product of the materials and high aspect ratio design and is not a design goal in itself. The benefit is, smooth ride during a turbulence.

Aerodynamically you do pay a penalty. However, to a certain extent this will be offset by lighter weight and the much superior strength, facilitates the high aspect ratio which more than make up for the loss due to the flex.

Comment: I came across that word once on the internet and couldn't find it again.  It starts with the letter "b".  Wing flex is probably one of the more common reference to it but that is not the word I'm trying to remember.

Comment: @DannLogue Ok. In that case I suspect you'll have to re word your question so that it captures the exact type of movement that you are referring to. My answer above is based on the question that you have asked. If the above answer is not of any help, please let me know if I should delete it. Thanks.