# What is the effect of wing flex on wing's airfoil shape and its performance effect on wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, lift, airfoil

There are good amount of discussion on [wing flex](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14719/is-wing-flex-good) in this forum.

I am more interested in understanding the effect of flex on aerofoil shape of the wing and its impact on flight performance.

Do designers take into account the cross sectional shape change induced by wing flex while designing the aircraft? If not, is it because the effects are negligible or simply too complicated to simulate?

Also, does the shape change induced by wing flex help in improving the performance?