# Why do some aircraft have wings that tend to bend up?

Tags: aircraft-design

I take regular visits to the Boeing website, and when I look at some pictures, the wings tend to edge/point up. Why is this?

Comment: Are you asking about that bent bit at the end?  (Winglets - see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2111/52) for a picture)

Comment: Are you asking about [winglets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingtip_device) or [flexible wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_wing)?

Comment: @Farhan I think he's referring to the dihedral angle

Comment: @TomMcW: Or it could be the upward flexing of the wings while in flight?  Which has an answer here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/838/what-are-the-effects-of-the-boeing-787s-very-flexible-wings

Comment: The quality of the answer depends on the quality of the question you ask - ask clearly, precisely, and concisely. Also, welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange! : )

Answer (score 3):

All wings do flex, but in some modern airliners, the wings are built, fully or in part, with modern composites, that may deform within a larger elastic interval than metals...